# JavaScript - making sure a date is valid

Tags: javascript, html, date, validation

I have 3 drop down boxes to show a start date (day/month/year). I have 3 more to show an end date.

I wish to validate that

- The user picks a valid date (i.e not the 30th February). If they pick an invalid date, alert("Your date is invalid.")
- That the difference in days between the start and end dates is less than 7.

I am really struggling with this and was hoping someone could help me as a relative beginner.

My code so far is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var monthtext=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"];

    function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield){
    var today=new Date()
    var dayfield=document.getElementById(dayfield)
    var monthfield=document.getElementById(monthfield)
    var yearfield=document.getElementById(yearfield)
    for (var i=0; i<=31; i++)
       dayfield.options[i]=new Option(i, i)
    dayfield.options[today.getDate()]=new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(),     true, true) //select today's day
    for (var m=0; m<12; m++)
      monthfield.options[m]=new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
    monthfield.options[today.getMonth()]=new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
    var thisyear=today.getFullYear()
    for (var y=0; y<4; y++){
      yearfield.options[y]=new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
      thisyear+=1
    }
    yearfield.options[0]=new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
        <label>Start date :</label>
            <select name="startDateDay" id="startDaydropdown"></select> 
            <select name="startDateMonth" id="startMonthdropdown"></select> 
            <select name="startDateYear" id="startYeardropdown"></select>

        <label>End date :</label>
            <select name="endDateDay" id="endDaydropdown"></select> 
            <select name="endDateMonth" id="endMonthdropdown"></select> 
            <select name="endDateYear" id="endYeardropdown"></select>
```

Comment: You can use the jquery datepicker where you disallow the user to select past date. Then make the to date in the to section to start from 7 days in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have two text fields to let the user type in the date, then let `new Date(textfield.value)` do the heavy lifting of date validation?

Then you only need to worry about determining that the dates are within 7 days of each other. You can do that part fairly easily with the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), perhaps with something as simple as:

```
var dateDiff = date2.getTime()  - date1.getTime();
if(dateDiff <= 1000*60*60*24*7 && dateDiff > 0) {
    return 'valid';
} else {
    return 'invalid';
}
```

If running this as part of the submit button, your code would be something like:

```
function validateDatesOnSubmit() {
    var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value);
    var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value);
    if(date1 == "Invalid Date" || date2 == "Invalid Date") {
        alert("You have entered an invalid date, please fix this.");
        return false;
    }
    var dateDiff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    if(dateDiff <= 1000*60*60*24*7 && dateDiff >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("You have entered a range beyond one week, please reduce the number of days selected.");
        return false;
    }
}
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = validateDatesOnSubmit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to do this now. In this case, what would my JavaScript function be? I am trying to write it now, but am having difficulty extracting the values and putting them into the JavaScript correctly.

Comment: Well, when do you want it called? When they click a submit button?

Comment: that would be perfect if possible, yes :)

Comment: I updated the answer with an example function and how to attach it to the form. But I think you need to read up on the Javascript Event Loop and how the Document Object Model fires events and then calls callbacks on those events; this is mostly the "dumb" glue code, here, so a better understanding of what you're trying to "glue together" will make these things obvious. ;)

Comment: @DavidEllis—you can't rely on the Date object to reliably parse a date string into an object across browsers. You must manually parse it (which isn't difficult).

Comment: @RobG: I don't see why not. The Date object is part of the spec and there's a minimum level of date format types they must all parse. Some will parse other formats, but it's not required, and in any case, if the end user doesn't type in a date in a common format, they'll just try a different format until it works.

Comment: @DavidEllis—you are relying on conformance to ES5, which is not good advice given that there are many browsers in current use that known to not be non–compliant (e.g. the new features of Date.parse). Even in ES5, implementations are only required to parse ISO8601 strings and the OP is not in ISO8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date is in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` then:

```
function toDate(t) {
  var t = t.split(/[-\/]/g);
  return new Date(t[2],t[1] - 1, t[0]);
}

function within7Days(t0, t1) {
  var d0 = toDate(t0);
  var d1 = toDate(t1);
  return d0.setDate(d0.getDate() + 7) > d1;
}

alert(within7Days('12-3/2012', '18/3/2012')); // true
alert(within7Days('12-3/2012', '19/3/2012')); // false
```

If the date can be before or after, you might want to use `Math.abs()`

#### Edit

Incidentally, **do not** trust `Date.parse`. In ECMA-262 ed 3 it is essentially implementation dependent. In ES5 it is specified as first attempting to parse the string as ISO8601, but after that, it is implementation idependant. IE (<9 at least) will not correctly parse an ISO8601 date string.

In any case, manually parsing a date is trivial.

Comment: By using the Date object's internal parser, you can be sure that a date format relevant to the locale of the end user is used, rather than forcing any particular format type on them (for instance, I'd type mm/dd/yyyy or dd-mmm-yyyy before dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: @DavidEllis—the built–in Date parser is not consistent across browsers, Date iteslf does not respect locale for input (why would you trust it anyway), even for `toLocaleString`, so the parser should not be used. The only safe way is to specify the format, validate input, parse it and deal with invalid strings. But that wasn't part of the OP. The OP states day/month/year, the above supports either '-' or '/' as a seperator.